# Should a List<T> parameter come before an object in a function?

Tags: c#, syntax

When coding a C# function, where the function has a `List<T>` and an object for the `List<T>`, should the `List<T>` parameter come before the object?

Here is some code to illustrate:

1. `void CheckList(List<Example> examples, Example example)`
2. `void CheckList(Example example, List<Example> examples)`

Is there a coding convention for the above situation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no coding convention that covers this case. Either one is fine. It's personal preference.

The only case when parameter order matters is when you have default values. In that case, anything with a default value must come after the other parameters.

Comment: Also, `params` parameters must go at the end, though default parameters and `params` are incompatible with each other.

Comment: +1 to this response.  My only admonition is, whatever convention you choose, *be consistent*!  The Law of Least Surprises applies here, too.

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention for this case. Unless explicitly disallowed by the compiler(optional parameters, params), you can do whatever you like with regards to the order of parameters.

Take note also that code conventions are just agreed upon way of coding. You are actually free to create your own coding convention as long it is agreed upon by your group/company. The important thing is consistency in following an agreed upon code convention.